# Bayesian word2vec

Tags: bayesian, pymc, stan

I'm trying to implement word2vec in pymc3 as shown here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb. Now I can implement everything with regards to the weights and biases. However, I don't know how to implement a `sampled_softmax_loss`. This function does negative sampling from a large set of labels. Is there a Bayesian equivalent (before you say this is Bayesian by default read on)?

The number of labels are ~15k. So doing a full softmax might be slow/ infeasible. I'm also thinking of using ADVI so **straight out sampling methods are out**. Why not use normal sampling? Well the hidden representations of those words/ labels are a 15000 x 100 matrix.

The closest Bayesian equivalent that I can think of is recommendation engines/ matrix factorisation.

I'd like to use stan but the batch processing capability is too good in pymc3 that I can't go past it. But I welcome any solutions from the stan community as well.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06571
Bayesian Skip-Gram is the VB version of word2vec